# jQuery UI Datepicker onchange event issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a JS code in which when you change a field it calls a search routine. The problem is that I can't find any jQuery events that will fire when the Datepicker updates the input field.

For some reason, a change event is not called when Datepicker updates the field. When the calendar pops up it changes the focus so I can't use that either. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up using https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132949/293792 since this appeared to directly answer the question

Answer (score 409, accepted):

You can use the datepicker's [`onSelect` event](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect).

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
    }
});
```

**Live example**:

```js
$(".date")
.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
    }
})
.on("change", function() {
    console.log("Got change event from field");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type='text' class='date'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, `onSelect` fires whenever a date is selected, even if it hasn't changed. This is a design flaw in the datepicker: It always fires `onSelect` (even if nothing changed), and *doesn't* fire any event on the underlying input on change. (If you look in the code of that example, we're listening for changes, but they aren't being raised.) It should probably fire an event on the input when things change (possibly the usual `change` event, or possibly a datepicker-specific one).

---

If you like, of course, you can make the `change` event on the `input` fire:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

That will fire `change` on the underlying `input` for any handler hooked up via jQuery. But again, it *always* fires it. If you want to only fire on a real change, you'll have to save the previous value (possibly via `data`) and compare.

**Live example**:

```js
$(".date")
.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
        $(this).change();
    }
})
.on("change", function() {
    console.log("Got change event from field");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type='text' class='date'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user760092: I posted this answer and then went out, and literally as I was leaving I thought "You know, you could trigger the `change` handler(s)" and so I've updated the answer with that. :-)

Comment: I hv a scenario where I am changing the date (using `setDate` option) programatically. Which event can handle this too..??

Comment: +1 Nice addition of firing the change event on the input here

Comment: I've gone round and round in circles trying to go get this to work in all scenarios and this has done it! Much appreciated!

Comment: Why in the world didn't they make those actual events?

Comment: This is for "selecting" and NOT for "change". If you select a date and  then re-select it, this event gets fired. Some developers will want to know when a date has changed from some initial state to know whether the data is "dirty" and needs to be saved. For this reason, I'm downvoting you on this.

Comment: @AndroidDev: I've clarified that. (*You* could have, of course; the goal of the site is to have *good answers*; respectful editing to achieve that is encouraged.)  It's a design flaw in the datepicker, not in the answer. (What it *should* do is fire a change event of some kind on the input, if and only if changing the date, but it doesn't.)

Comment: why doesn't this work when there is an icon-trigger..?

Comment: @BenSewards: Insufficient data. :-) Perhaps a fiddle? It would justify its own question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it turns out that there was a ton of minified js code that wasn't part of a library that already bound the onSelect event of the datepicker element. I also noticed that placing a simple alert in this section did not fire on change. Must be because of the way the minified code is set up..

Comment: or if the date picker has already been initialized use `$(".date").datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() { $(this).change();
  }
);`

Comment: it really is annoying that they don't fire the event when the underlying input changes, since it does update the datepicker

Comment: Thanks brad :) that was what I was looking for ^^ Wasn't sure it would have worked cause this is not indicated in the doc... It works like a charm !

Answer (score 79):

T.J. Crowder's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471992/481154) is very good and still remains accurate. **Triggering the change event within the onSelect function is as close as you're going to get.**

However, there is a nice property on the datepicker object (`lastVal`) that will allow you to **conditionally trigger the change event only on actual changes** without having to store the value(s) yourself:

```js
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
     onSelect: function(d,i){
          if(d !== i.lastVal){
              $(this).change();
          }
     }
});
```

Then just handle change events like normal:

```
$('#dateInput').change(function(){
     //Change code!
});
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this recently?  It doesn't work for me.  i.lastVal returns undefined and it doesn't appear to be one of the available properties.

Comment: I just implemented this with no issue at all. Works like a charm.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, lastval is no longer defined

Comment: @luke_mclachlan `lastVal` however is ;-)

Comment: `lastVal` does not exist on the datepicker object, at least in my testing. So this solution will always trigger the change.

Comment: @NicholasHead doesn't it? - `window.$.datepicker._getInst(document.getElementById("DatePickerElementId")).lastVal;`

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Does it just work with certain browsers or specific versions?

Answer (score 15):

Your looking for the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event in the datepicker object:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#inputfield').change(function() { 
    dosomething();
});
```

Comment: I thought this should work, but unfortunately not.  It's only triggered when the field is changed using the *keyboard*, not when selecting from the date-picker.  Annoying.

Comment: From the jQuery UI docs: "This widget manipulates its element's value programmatically, therefore a native change event may not be fired when the element's value changes."

Comment: The funny thing is that I am getting the **opposite** of that - when I change the input by hand via keyboard, no event is triggered. But when I change the value of the field through the widget, the change event gets fired. Odd.

Comment: This works fine when I change with keyboard and when I change with the date picker widget.

Comment: somehow this calls multiple times .

Answer (score 13):

I wrote this because I needed a solution to trigger an event only if the date changed.

It is a simple solution. Each time the dialog box closes we test to see if the data has changed. If it has, we trigger a custom event and reset the stored value.

```
$('.datetime').datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText,datePickerInstance) {
        var oldValue = $(this).data('oldValue') || "";
        if (dateText !== oldValue) {
            $(this).data('oldValue',dateText);
            $(this).trigger('dateupdated');
        }
    }
});
```

Now we can hook up handlers for that custom event...

```
$('body').on('dateupdated','.datetime', function(e) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I am using this with knockout, I could not get it to trigger an event when the user deleted or manually changed the date without selecting a date on the picker. Very helpful.

Comment: My issue with jQuery datepicker fields is not exactly the same as the one posted here. It is about the change event firing multiple times. I tried several solutions and this is the only one that actually works in my situation.

Comment: I did more or less the same as this solution and I think it definitely works the best. I will post what I did in a separate answer...

Answer (score 11):

I am using bootstrap-datepicker and none of above solution worked for me. This answer helped me ..

[bootstrap datepicker change date event doesnt fire up when manually editing dates or clearing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507671/bootstrap-datepicker-change-date-event-doesnt-fire-up-when-manually-editing-date)

Here is what I applied:

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({
     endDate: new Date(),
     autoclose: true,
 }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
        //my work here
    });
```

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question. But i couldnt get the jquery $(this).change() event to fire correctly onSelect. So i went with the following approach to fire the change event via vanilla js.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
     showOn: 'focus',
     dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     onSelect: function() {
         var event;
         if(typeof window.Event == "function"){
             event = new Event('change');
             this.dispatchEvent(event);
         }   else {
             event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
             event.initEvent('change', false, false);
             this.dispatchEvent(event);
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Error "'$' is undefined" for this snippet. Uh oh.

Comment: You're dispatching a change event in the onSelect event which isn't quite the desired effect since select will fire each time a date is clicked but it doesn't necessarily mean the date was actually changed i.e. the user might have clicked the same date twice.

Comment: @Jacques you are correct. i believe you could compare String dateText to this.value and only fire this if they are different.

Comment: @Michael12345 i see what you mean. i have modified it so that its no longer a snippet. my apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
$('#idPicker').on('changeDate', function() {
    var date = $('#idPicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
 onSelect: function(){
       $(this).trigger('change');
      }
 }});
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 4):

On jQueryUi 1.9 I've managed to get it to work through an additional data value and a combination of beforeShow and onSelect functions:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    beforeShow: function( el ){
        // set the current value before showing the widget
        $(this).data('previous', $(el).val() );
    },

    onSelect: function( newText ){
        // compare the new value to the previous one
        if( $(this).data('previous') != newText ){
            // do whatever has to be done, e.g. log it to console
            console.log( 'changed to: ' + newText );
        }
    }
});
```

Works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Manual says:

```
apply.daterangepicker: Triggered when the apply button is clicked, or when a predefined range is clicked
```

So:

```
$('#daterange').daterangepicker({
  locale: { cancelLabel: 'Clear' }  
});

$('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function() {
  alert('worked!');
});
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

My soluthion:

```
var $dateInput = $('#dateInput');

$dateInput.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(f,d,i){
        if(d !== i.lastVal){
            $dateInput.trigger("change");
        }
    }
}).data('datepicker');

$dateInput.on("change", function () {
   //your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may lie in how your datepicker is setup.
Why don't you disconnect the input... do not use altField. Instead explicitly set the values when the onSelect fires. This will give you control of each interaction; the user text field, and the datepicker.

Note: Sometimes you have to call the routine on .change() and not .onSelect() because onSelect can be called on different interactions that you are not expecting.

Pseudo Code:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    //altField: , //do not use
    onSelect: function(date){
        $('#date').val(date); //Set my textbox value
        //Do your search routine
    },
}).change(function(){
    //Or do it here...
});

$('#date').change(function(){
    var thisDate = $(this).val();
    if(isValidDate(thisDate)){
        $('#date').datepicker('setDate', thisDate); //Set my datepicker value
        //Do your search routine
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker selected value change event code below

```
/* HTML Part */
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

/* jQuery Part */
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
                selectedDate= $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
                alert(selectedDate);        
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wdcalendar this going to help you

```
 $("#PatientBirthday").datepicker({ 
        picker: "<button class='calpick'></button>",
        onReturn:function(d){
          var today = new Date();
          var birthDate = d;
          var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
          var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
          if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
          }

          $('#ageshow')[0].innerHTML="Age: "+age;
          $("#PatientBirthday").val((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' +  d.getFullYear());
        }
      });
```

the event onReturn works for me

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
events: {
    'apply.daterangepicker #selector': 'function'
}
```

Comment: Does not apply to jQuery UI Datepicker, which is the topic of this question. Also, doesn't mention for which random javascript library this is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Some of you may be using something called `XDSoft DateTimePicker` https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

There, the change event is

```
onSelectDate: function(){
  alert('change date event);
}
```

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onSelectDate

Comment: This question is about the jQuery UI DatePicker component. I know there are answers here about many other plugins, but those should really be in separate questions that are tagged appropriately.

Comment: I came here thinking I was using jQuery UI DatePicker because they look exactly the same, `.datetimepicker({..})`. Only through browsing the answers did I discover my plugin was actually a different one, similar to Bootstrap. So this is a valid post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onClose` option for the `datepicker` and put your change code inside. This triggers when the `datepicker` modal is closed. I tried to trigger the change event but that wouldn't work so I put my code inside of the `onClose` instead and it works.  The same may work for `onSelect` that was mentioned if you need to trigger when the date is selected.

```
$('#el').datepicker({ 
   onClose: function () {
     // code here
   }
});
```

Datepicker options https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score -1):

This approach is simple and works everytime with textbox control.  `$('#controlID').on('changeDate', function() { $(this).change(); });`

Comment: "works everytime"... IF AND ONLY if you happen to be using some datepicker component that generates some custom "changeDate" event. You don't mention which one you use. jQuery UI Datepicker, which this question is about, does not have such an event.