# Migrate bootstrap-datepicker to jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

In bootstrap-datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ this work:

```
$('#form_field').datepicker().on('changeDate', calc_func);
```

but in jQuery UI not working. How to fix/change it?
`changeDate` is event in bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help

Comment: @PSR How to put `calc_func` to `onSelect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        calc_func();
    }
});
```

when you select or change date in jQuery calender then the function will be called

Comment: Some explanation is normally needed along the answers