# advice for an MVC dynamic page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, event-handling

I would like to start off by making that statement that I have only been using **MVC** for a little over a week now (mostly small local c# projects before).

My goal for this page would be to have the `DatePicker` input populate some more text boxes on the page using an `OnChange` event. Not looking for someone to do this for me, just point me in a direction around ***best practice***.

[image]

Comment: can you say, you want to populate other textboxes form server data or localy on page?

Comment: local, for example, you pick a date using the date picker, and then 11 more fields will appear using the same day but each one adding 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way, if you have a form with a fields and already know all the fields name id to create your fields on `View` and make them `hidden`. Then, when you change the value in `DataPicker` field you update the values and show shem via `JavaScript`. There is some problems with `DataPicker` `OnChange` event but there is a good question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471992/1849444) on this theme.

Hope this help you to chouse right direction