# Getting datepicker starting value after selecting another value from another datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

So the idea is I have 2 datepickers. I want to get the second datepicker `minDate` value by selecting the first datepicker value. 
For instance: 
If I choose the first datepicker value to be 22-03-2015 the second datepicker value will start from 23-03-2015
**or** If I choose 13-05-2015 the second datepicker value will start from 14-05-2015. How do I achieve that. This is what i tried:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
     minDate: 'today',
     yearRange: "2015:2016",
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
});
$(".datepicker2").datepicker({
     minDate: 1,
     yearRange: "2015:2016",
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the `minDate` option for datepicker2 after datepicker1's value has changed:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="datepicker1" />
<input id="datepicker2" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("input").datepicker();

$("#datepicker1").change(function() {
   var minDate = $(this).val();
   $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ke8LowuL/

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the onSelect event assuming you are using 'jquery datepicker'

[JQuery Datepicker onchange event help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help)