# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have two date datepicker area and i want set the my finish date by my `startDate + myText` value like 3,5,2(day) but i get error in this line `$("#finishDate").setDate(startDate + inputDate);`
give me

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setDate is not a function"

How can i do this. Thanks.

```
 $("#myText").on('change', function () {
                var startDate = $('#startDate').val();                
                var inputDay = $('#myText').val();
                $("#finishDate").setDate(startDate + inputDay);
 });
```

Comment: Maybe you need `.val()` or `.html()` depending on the `#finishDate` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Datepicker: setDate is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104353/jquery-datepicker-setdate-is-not-a-function)

Comment: im already try this method sir or i could not.

Answer (score 0):

> try using this

```
$(document).on('change', "#myText", function () {
     var startDate = $('#startDate').val();                
     var inputDay = $('#myText').val();
     $('#finishDate').val(startDate + inputDay).datepicker('setDate', new Date(startDate));
     //$('#finishDate').val(startDate + inputDay).datepicker('setDate', startDate); //based on your date format
 });
```

Comment: sir im not get any error but it is not set to finishDate.

Comment: whether it is input type.

Comment: what do you mean sir.

Comment: "<input type="text" name="myFile" id="finishDate">" whether it is like this

Comment: " <input type="text" class="form-control m-input m-datepicker" placeholder="choose" id="finishDate" name="finishDate" />" it is like this.

Comment: i did in $(document) in above try using that