# Event calendar in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to do a form like the following:

[image]

When clicked on the first text box it should display a dropdown

Then if I click in one of the three boxes it should display a calendar as the picture shows:

[image]

When clicking on the button it should give me the name chosen from the first box and the days chosen from the different date boxes.

[image]

I have no idea idea of how to do the date functionality and my jquery or php do not go as far.

Please help

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help

Comment: Check [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)

Comment: Use this for dropdown: [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for data functionality

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Date: `<input type="text" id="datepicker">`

Comment: I managed to get part of it working using the datepicker as you can see in my snippet.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM
How can I put each date in a variable and alert it?

Comment: var travel = document.getElementById("textboxidj").value;     alert(travel );

Comment: Use this jquery too:   somevariable = $("#textboxid").val();