# Check Birth date is less than current date of the system?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

```
 <div class="col-sm-5">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateDate(){
            var selectedDate = $('#form-control datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
            var now = new Date();
            now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            if (selectedDate < now) {
                // selected date is in the past
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" name="birth_date" class="form-control datepicker" id="field-1" onsubmit="validateDate()">
</div>
```

Does not validate the input date using this javascript.
want to insert a date which is less than the current date.

Comment: I'd suggest tidying your code and then using the code block feature of the question editor to make sure your content displays correctly. Also "does not validate" is not a great problem description. Check out [ask], [help], and [mcve].

Comment: an input doesn't have an onsubmit event

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you would like the JavaScript to prevent form submission when the `selectedDate` is less than `now`. To transfer this information, you need to `return false;` in your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validateDate(){
  var selectedDate = $('#form-control datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  var now = new Date();
  now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  if (selectedDate < now) {
   // selected date is in the past
   return false;
  }
 }
</script>
```

To get this JavaScript function open, you need a `<form>` with an `onsubmit` that `return`s the value of the JavaScript function, as well as a way to submit the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateDate();">
 <input type="text" name="birth_date" class="form-control datepicker" id="field-1">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: need to change the id on the javascript then it worked.
I want to be able to select a birth date that corresponds from 1 year old to 100 years old (1 century) that is the input must less than the current date of system thus giving me the option to choose not less than 1 century.
Can u help me on that javascript? :(

<script type="text/javascript">
                       function validateDate(){
                        var selectedDate = $('#field-1').datepicker('getDate');

Comment: @Harish try seeing what you can do with selectedDate.getFullYear() and now.getFullYear()

Answer (score 0):

`input` elements don't have a `submit` event; `form`s do. Assuming you want your code to run when the user presses return, you need to:

- Wrap the `input` in a `form` element and use the `form`'s `onSubmit` attribute
- Return false from your handler when the validation has failed

See [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to this question.

[JQuery Datepicker onchange event help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help)

You may want to attach an event/function to date picker to do the validation.

If it is any other field, you may attach onchange or onkeyup event to a validation (the way you have tried to do with onsubmit).