# How to add One day in date-picker range in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use 2 input for `date-picker` for `from-date` and `to-date` at project.

I need after select `from-date`, change `to-date` with add 1 day in `to-date`.

For example:

I select `2017-01-01` in `from-date`, I need change `to-date` to `2017-01-02`.

My Code:

```
$( function() {
$(".date-picker-fa").datepicker({isRTL:!0,dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd"});
var dateFormat = "yy/mm/dd",
    from = $( "#dateFromHotel" )
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            isRTL:!0,
            dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd"
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
            to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
    to = $( "#dateToHotel" ).datepicker({
        isRTL:!0,
        dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd"
    })
        .on( "change", function() {
            from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
        });

function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
    }
    return date;
}
```

} );

How to add One day in `to-date` after select date in `from-date`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6471992/5513005) might help you

Comment: hi @YashKaranke, No ! i add One day to `to-date` after select date in `from-date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
        date = date2;
    } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
```