# JQuery : Event not getting triggered while changing date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to call a function whenever user changes date in a datepicker but it is not working. I have already checked link for Question [JQuery Datepicker onchange event help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help) but it didnt help.

Below is my code and what i have tried:

```
<h:inputText id="animalBornDateId"
value="#{myController.animalBornDate}"
styleClass="dtp dateClass" style="width: 80px !important;" >
</h:inputText>
```

What i tried:

```
$("#animalBornDateId").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        alert('on select triggered');

    }
});
```

Another:

```
$('#animalBornDateId').on('input',function(e){
                 alert('Changed!')
                });
```

The below works when i manually enter date inside textbox and click tab which i dont want.

```
 $('#animalBornDateId').change(function() { 
                alert("test");
            });
```

I want to call alert function when i select date from the calendar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Datepicker onchange event help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help)

Comment: Sir, I have already tried but didnt work.. Please check the possible scenarios i have tried

Comment: How you wrapped this code in document ready or self execute function ?

Comment: No i am using it document.ready