# How do I set an "onchange" event of a Razor "EditorFor" with a Date field?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor `EditorFor` for a field of type Date :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc)
```

I want to set a "change" event on the generated datepicker but I don't find a solution to get an event when the value in the input is changed manually OR with the calendar.

I tried with a JavaScript listener :

```
$("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc").on("change", function () {
    alert("ok");
});
```

It work with a manually change in the input but not with the calendar.

I tried to add the "onchange" event

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc, new { onchange = "myFunction" })
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc, new { onchange = "myFunction()" })
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Here is the generated HTML code :

```
<div class="input-append date" id="AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent" data-date="">
    <input class="span2 valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field 'Date de fin de disponibilité' must be a date." id="AvailableEndDateTimeUtc" name="AvailableEndDateTimeUtc" type="text" value="" aria-describedby="AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-error" aria-invalid="false">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

This code is generate when I use this syntax :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc, new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent()" })

$(function () {
    var c = Globalize.culture().calendars.standard;
    var fmt = c.patterns["d"];
    $("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent").datetimepicker({ 
        language: 'glob', 
        format: fmt,
        pickDate: true, 
        pickTime: false, 
        pickSeconds: false, 
        pick12HourFormat: false,
        maskInput: true, 
        collapse: true });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to add that code :

```
$('#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent').change(function () {
    alert("Select change");
});
```

But it is triggered only when I do a manual change in the input too.

I tried to get the datepicker and add the event on it (I saw in the docs that it has a 'onSelect' event) but it breaks the generated component.

Last attempt for this edit : get the existing datepicker options and add my event

```
$("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent").data("datetimepicker").options.OnChangeDate = function() {
    alert("Select change");
}
```

I put that code on the `document.ready` but `$("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent").data("datetimepicker")` return "undefined". But if I do the same in the console, it returns the component.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a jQuery datepicker underneath, so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue

Comment: The generated HTML is an input element?

Comment: I edit the question with the generated HTML.

Comment: Is the generated datepicker a plugin? It may well be intercepting the click event. If it is a plugin, it should have a way of manipulating the events as part of the api.

Comment: I don't know if it's a plugin behind, I'm looking to know if it's a jQuery datePicker as @Andrei said

Comment: Yes @DanielGale, I add it to the question.

Comment: "AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent", it's in the question.

Comment: It looks like you need to call `OnChangeEvent()` from a change event handler for  `$("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent")` also. Is this a bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery or some other one?

Comment: A `<div>` does not have a `.change()` event!

Comment: It generate a jQuery datepicker yes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `onChangeDateTime` setting will allow you to call the OnChangeEvent().

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc)

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc').change(function(){
    OnChangeEvent();
});


$(function () {
    var c = Globalize.culture().calendars.standard;
    var fmt = c.patterns["d"];
    $("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent").datetimepicker({ 
        onChangeDateTime: OnChangeEvent, /* Add onChangeDateTime event */
        language: 'glob', 
        format: fmt,
        pickDate: true, 
        pickTime: false, 
        pickSeconds: false, 
        pick12HourFormat: false,
        maskInput: true, 
        collapse: true });
});


function OnChangeEvent(){
    alert('Changed!');
}

</script>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: The `$('#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent').change(...` is triggered when I manually change the value in the input and not when I select in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it seems you are using wrong id for `onchange` function.

instead of using `#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent` you are using `#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc)

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    var c = Globalize.culture().calendars.standard;
    var fmt = c.patterns["d"];
    $("#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent").datetimepicker({ 
        language: 'glob', 
        format: fmt,
        pickDate: true, 
        pickTime: false, 
        pickSeconds: false, 
        pick12HourFormat: false,
        maskInput: true, 
        collapse: true });
});
$('#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent').change(function(){
    // do your logic here
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `$('#AvailableEndDateTimeUtc-parent').change(...` is triggered when I manually change the value in the input and not when I select in the calendar.