# Jquery datepicker events

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I would like to fire an event each time a date is selected in my datepicker using jquery, but I can't do what i want. I saw there was a "changeDate" event, but I guess I'm not using it properly.

Do you know the way it works ?

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker" id="publication" data-date="<?php echo $date_publication; ?>" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <input class="input-small" name="date_publication" size="16" type="text" value="<?php echo dateUStoFR($date_publication); ?>"/>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Jquery side 
    `$('.input-small').datepicker().on('changeDate', alert('test'));`

Thanks for your assistance.

The quesiton isn't about onSelect, or may be it is, but I don't understand how: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker onchange event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or jquery datepicker ?