# jQuery Datepicker on change event is not getting fired when using button instead of text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make a button only datepicker with jQuery dtaepicker.

When I am attaching the datepicker to an input, the onchange function works and I got the new selected value.

However when I am attaching the datepicker with just a button or something else, the onchange event is not getting fired:

```
<input type="text" class="test"> // works

<i class="fa fa-calendar test"></i> // opens the datepicker as should be, but not fire the change event

$(function() {
            $(".test").datepicker({
              format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
              onSelect: function(v) {
                // also not getting fired
              },
            }).on("change", function() {
              // not getting fired when using button instead of text input
              let val = $(this).val();
            });
        });
```

Comment: This event related to form elements (input, select).

Comment: to me onSelect is working: http://jsfiddle.net/evhnrLaq/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found it:**

```
$(".test").datepicker(params).on('hide', v => console.log(v.date));
// will return a date object with the selected date
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this line `showOn: 'button'`

```
<input type="text" class="test"> // works

<i class="fa fa-calendar test"></i> // opens the datepicker as should be, but not fire the change event

$(function() {
            $(".test").datepicker({
              showOn: 'button', // use showOn: 'both' if you want to open the datepicker on icon and the input as well
              format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
              onSelect: function(v) {
                // This would get fired on changing date on the calendar icon
              },
            }).on("change", function() {
              // not getting fired when using button instead of text input
              let val = $(this).val();
            });
        });
```

Also, you can remove the `<i class="fa fa-calendar test"></i>` tag and place the following two LOC after the showOn attribute to show the calendar icon

```
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hide` event - it gets fire after you finish inserting or picking a date:

```
$(function() {
            $(".test").datepicker({
              format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
              onSelect: function(v) {
                // also not getting fired
              },
            }).on("hide", function(e) {
              // not getting fired when using button instead of text input
              let val = $(this).val();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue#answer-6471992).

You should be able to call the datepicker change from the button click event