# Javascript event not working with datetime picker

Tags: javascript

When I am using a script for datetime picker on form field for time, my javascript onchange event on that form field is not working

I have tried other javascript events like onblur , onfocusout but none worked.

Below is my form

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input onchange="SetScheduleDate()" class="form-control" id="datepicker-13" oninput="this.className = ''" name="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY*" type="text" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" />
 </div>                                       
 <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <label>Time</label>
    <input onchange="SetScheduleTime()"  oninput="this.className = ''" name="time" id="ttime" placeholder="00:00:00*" type="text" />
 </div>
</form>
```

This is where I am showing date and time using javascript onchange event

```
<h4>SCHEDULED DATE AND TIME</h4>
<P> 
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
<span id="schedule_date"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
<span id="schedule_time"></span> 
</P>
```

This is my script for datetimepicker and for javascript onchange event function call

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>

<script src="js/jquery.timeselector.js"></script> 

<script>
    $(function() {
    $('[id="ttime"]').timeselector({ min: '09:30', max: '18:30' })
    });
</script>

<script>

function SetScheduleDate()
  {
    var date=$('[name=date]').val();
    $('#schedule_date').html(date);


  }

  function SetScheduleTime()
  {
    var time=$('[name=time]').val();
    $('#schedule_time').html(time);

  }

</script>
```

I am getting result from SetScheduleDate() function but not from SetScheduleTime().

Please anybody tell Why SetScheduleTime() is not triggering.

Comment: use datepicker events

Comment: are you using jQuery UI datepicker ? or bootstrap?

Comment: @PranavCBalan - I am using <script src="js/jquery.timeselector.js"></script>  for time field

Comment: `.datepicker()` ????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datepicker onchange event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue)

Comment: @AnshuR : share its documentation or website link

Comment: Just use `$( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText) { /* your code */}});`

Comment: @skobaljic - datepicker is working fine and i am getting date also from SetScheduleDate() but when i am using timeselector it is not triggering onchange event to call SetScheduleTime() function