# How can I disable an input type date with jQuery if the first input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working at a checkout page. I need to disable an input (#dreturn) if the previous input (dpick) is empty.

This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var minDate = new Date();
    $("#dpick").datepicker({
        showAnim: 'drop',
        numberOfMonth: 1,
        maxDate: 7,
        minDate: minDate,
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        onClose : function(selectedDate){
            $('#dreturn').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }});
        var minDate = new Date();
    $("#dreturn").datepicker({
        showAnim: 'drop',
        numberOfMonth: 1,
        maxDate: 7,
        minDate: minDate,
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        onClose : function(selectedDate){
            $('#dreturn').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }});
```

This is my datapicker but this isn't helping me.

```
    $('#dreturn').change(function() {
     var start = $('#dpick').datepicker('getDate');
     var end   = $('#dreturn').datepicker('getDate');

     if (start<end) {
      var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
      $('#days').val(days);
     }
     else {
      alert ("Please chech again your dates!");
      $('#dpick').val("");
      $('#dreturn').val("");
      $('#days').val("");
     }
    });
```

I've tried this but isn't working.

```
if (!'dpick').val() {
    document.getElementById("dreturn").disabled = true;
}
});
```

Comment: `if (!'dpick').val() {` <= this has at least 3 syntax errors.  First you are not doing a jquery method call there with `$(selector)` and your selector is wrong.  The `!` also does not go in the selector.  And the `if` expression's `()` is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to

`if(!Date.parse($("dpick").val())){`

and move this if to blur event handler, something like this

```
 $("#dpick").blur(function (){
  if(!Date.parse($(this).val())){
    document.getElementById("dreturn").disabled = true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("dreturn").disabled= false;
  }
})
```

Comment: "if(!$("dpick").val()){" thanks, this works but after I pick the date in "dpick" it remains disabled

Comment: I have assumed it is an id. Kindly check it

Comment: Yes, it is an id, I've modified it when you send me that answer but still doesn't work.

Comment: This time, I had change the event from on change to blur.

Answer (score 0):

Initially disable the second date-picker "#dreturn" after initializing your date-pickers:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        //initialization
        $("#dpick").datepicker({...});
        $("#dreturn").datepicker({...});

        $("#dreturn").prop('disabled',true);



         /****************** new code to be inserted see below ************/


});
```

Now, on the change of "#dpick"  enable "#dreturn":

```
/************************ CODE TO BE INSERTED ABOVE ****************/

$("#dpick").change"(
    function()
    {
      var val= $("#dpick").val();

      if(!(val))
      {
            $("#dreturn").prop('disabled',false);
      }
    }

   );
```

**Note: 
1. "** *if(val)"  evaluates to true if "val" is not null, undefined and the jQuery UI documentation states 
for the datepicker in https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate that the default value is "null".*
**2.** *Now to use "change()" for the datepicker of jQuery UI, check [jQuery Datepicker onchange event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-issue) which 
 so, it means you have to use "onSelect"  of jQuery datepicker UI to address the defect of your datepicker.*

```
   $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                //initialization
                 $("#dpick").datepicker({
                                             showAnim: 'drop',
                                            numberOfMonth: 1,
                                            maxDate: 7,
                                            minDate: minDate,
                                            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                                            onClose : function(selectedDate){
                                                $('#dreturn').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                                            },
                                             onSelect: function(){
                                                            $(this).change();
                                            }
                            });
                 $("#dreturn").datepicker({.....});


                 $("#dreturn").prop('disabled',true);


                    $("#dpick").change"(
                                        function()
                                        {
                                          var val= $("#dpick").val();

                                          if(val)
                                          {
                                                $("#dreturn").prop('disabled',false);
                                          }
                                        }

                                       );


            }


);
```

And your problem should be solved. Hope it helps. :-)